# AngularJS form validation not working with jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker

### Angular js bootstrap datepicker 3 validtion yyyy-mm-dd format

I am validating a bootstrap datepicker field but it is not working as expected,

1.value is appending through jquery but $valid is not able to trigger that.
($touched is working fine).

And
2. I want only yyyy-mm-dd format how can I do it..? (is there any patter validations there in angular.?).

```html
<form name="postJobForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Target Hiring Date 
    <br>
        touched---------{{postJobForm.hiring_date.$touched}}     
        <br>
        dirty---------{{postJobForm.hiring_date.$dirty}}
        <br>
        valid----------{{postJobForm.hiring_date.$valid }} --
        
    <small class="requiredFeild">*</small>  </label>
    <div class='input-group date' id='hiring_date'>
        <input name="hiring_date" ng-model="hiring_date"   type='text'
               data-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"  ng-required="true" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <small ng-show="postJobForm.hiring_date.$error.required && postJobForm.hiring_date.$touched" class="errorMsg ">Please complete this required field.</small>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is how I am initializing date picker

```
$('#hiring_date').datetimepicker({ 
            viewMode: 'months',
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            pickTime: false
            }).on('dp.change', function (ev) {
               
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Use [tag:angular-ui-datepicker]

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: thanks, it is working as expected..! @georgeawg